# Is the Southern Poverty Law Center A Political or Information Organization?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-speech, lgbt+, racism

I have read in many of the answers in Politics.SE references to the SPLC. The assumption is that SPLC is a prestigious enough organization that their information is authoritative.  It is not just here on this site, but both celebrities and politician also grant the SPLC authoritative status on their articles regarding anything related to hate speech or hate organizations.

On the other hand, There are articles (referencing opinions sometimes) that show that people and organizations have been falsely added to the SPLC list of hate speech. I am aware that anyone or any organization may say what they will and it is not necessarily true that they don't belong there

My personal experience is that I have not found anything in the SPLC website that is immediately false. In fact, some articles list hate-speech from people and organizations that one would think are liberal, including liberals that became nationalist white supremacist.

In the end, I am not sure how much to trust an organization that has a political agenda. However, if there is one, I don't know what the polical agenda is for the SPLC. Are they simply trying to get the word out but do not want to influence policy? Do they want to influence policy to help society?

I was not clear enough as pointed out by the comment. Wikipedia is an example of an organization that exists for information. Some of the information listed there is incorrect, some of it is political, but there is no intent on influencing political agendas.  NRA is an example of an organization that uses information for a political agenda.  Now I am pro NRA politically but I can see that the information on their articles is picked to influence the agenda. The SPLC role is not clear to me. Is the SPLC more wikipedia or NRA?

Comment: I'm not so sure that the distinction between a "political" or "information" organization can be really answered without some form of subjective line drawing. People have been erroneously added to TSA's no-fly list, would that make them a "political", or "information" organization? If you disagree with the "information" they provide, does that then make them (and/or those disagreeing) "political"?

Comment: In that the groups that track tend to advocate for changes in policy, I think it's fair to say the SPLC is certainly a group heavily involved in politics.

Comment: I also think you may be overthinking things. There's no reason to *not* trust any group just because they are political. You can certainly trust the NRA to back up gun interests, for example. You just need to be aware of the angle they are coming at in regards to tackling issues. Nearly *every* organization (political or otherwise) wants to influence people, society, consumers, etc.

Comment: @blip, The NRA does back up gun interest. With that in mind, if I need to find out if the new Glock is worth buying, i will trust them, If I need to know the number of gun owners who aren't vetted properly in gun shows, i will have a more difficult time. In that vein, will SPLC fairly judge those in the black list or does their agenda leans towards, the-bigger-the-list-the-bigger-the-problem-and-the-more-political-influence?

Comment: You might be interested that there exist people who disagree that wikipedia exists for information. rather than politics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Wikipedia#Systemic_bias_in_coverage

Comment: @origimbo, those who "control/created" wikipedia are human and have political agendas like anyone else. The problem is that their creation is out of their control in many ways. The shear volume prevents any kind of guidance. However, I can absolutely trust the article on the Mandelbrot set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SPLC was originally focused on hate groups but there have been some legitimate concerns of late. The SPLC page on [hate groups says](https://www.splcenter.org/issues/hate-and-extremism)

> The SPLC is the premier U.S. organization monitoring the activities of domestic hate groups and other extremists – including the Ku Klux Klan, white nationalists, the neo-Nazi movement, antigovernment militias and others.
>
> Over the years, we’ve crippled or destroyed some of the country’s most notorious hate groups – including the United Klans of America, the Aryan Nations and the White Aryan Resistance – by suing them for murders and other violent acts committed by their members or by exposing their activities.

These groups are all widely considered dangerous or extremist. Some advocate violence or openly racist activities. It was hard work, but the SPLC did some good in fighting groups like that.

The problem is that they shifted gears a few years ago and began listing political action groups, like the [Family Research Council](https://www.splcenter.org/fighting-hate/extremist-files/group/family-research-council), that oppose LGBT rights (there are [several more in that list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_organizations_designated_by_the_Southern_Poverty_Law_Center_as_anti-LGBT_hate_groups#Notable_groups_listed)) and individuals like [Charles Murray](https://www.splcenter.org/fighting-hate/extremist-files/individual/charles-murray). So you have a list that contains openly extremist groups (some advocating violence) and some that the SPLC disagrees with politically.

As David French noted, people then start lumping the extremists together with the political, [sometimes with negative results](http://www.nationalreview.com/article/449476/splcs-dangerous-lies-alliance-defending-freedom-no-hate-group)

> Last year, a radical mob tried to physically attack American Enterprise Institute scholar Charles Murray. He escaped unharmed, but a female professor who tried to protect him was injured, suffering a concussion and other injuries as the mob surged toward Murray. What helped motivate the mob? The SPLC’s absurd designation of Murray as a “white nationalist.”
>
> It would be unfair to hold the SPLC responsible for these violent acts. After all, the ultimate moral responsibility for violence rests with the criminal. But we all know that speech has power. It can influence men to do great good or inflict great harm. The SPLC is using its speech to inflict harm, to express its own form of hate, and to spread misinformation and deception throughout the land.

Comment: This answer is doing the same as Brythan's. It's not answering the question directly, but is making a statement that there are groups that shouldn't be considered hate groups...based purely on your opinion. Note that they aren't about tracking 'extremists'. They are about tracking 'hate groups'. Political groups that actively advocate for denying equal rights can certainly be legitimately considered a hate group by many people's definitions--despite it not matching *your* personal definition.

Comment: @blip You seem to have misunderstood. The reason the list holds any power at all is that the SPLC has gone after extremist groups. Suddenly changing the meaning and adding groups that are different from those you previously fought is a deliberate attempt to drag those you disagree with down to the level that almost nobody disagrees with. There are real world consequences to this. The Daily Stormer, a white nationalist site, recently lost its domain name and hosting. Imagine what happens if someone says "Nobody on the SPLC list can own a domain name or host with us"

Comment: mmm...I guess that's an opinion but I don't think everyone would agree the only reason the SPLC holds power is just because they went after the KKK. In *your opinion* you feel a hate group is different than an extremist group, and that's fine, but in *other people's opinion* they aren't all that unrelated at all.

Comment: `you have a list that contains openly extremist groups (some advocating violence) and some that the SPLC disagrees with politically` -> What's the difference? Jim Crow is a political policy; opposing that is no more or less "political" as opposing the FRC. Not saying I agree or disagree with FRC's listing – I haven't looked in to it and don't really have an opinion – just that I don't see how it's essentially different than listing groups that advocate Jim Crow laws (which, certainly at the time, was "mainstream" politically).

Comment: I would go so far as to say that, with their pivot to attacking non-violent organizations who simply hold policies that they disagree with, often provoking violence by doing so (see the Murray example above, or any of several others,) the SPLC has become a *de facto* hate group themselves.  Let he who hunts monsters beware...

Answer (score 12):

> Wikipedia is an example of an organization that exists for information. Some of the information listed there is incorrect, some of it is political, but there is no intent on influencing political agendas. NRA is an example of an organization that uses information for a political agenda.
>   The SPLC role is not clear to me. Is the SPLC more wikipedia or NRA?

Slavery, racial segregation, and extermination of all Jews are 'valid' political viewpoints that have been codified in law more than once. The SPLC considers these viewpoints to be bad, and spends time and effort to fight against movements that promote such policies.

[An example from their website](https://www.splcenter.org/issues/hate-and-extremism):

> Over the years, we’ve crippled or destroyed some of the country’s most notorious hate groups – including the United Klans of America, the Aryan Nations and the White Aryan Resistance – by suing them for murders and other violent acts committed by their members or by exposing their activities.

Therefore, by your definition, the SPLC is more "political" than "informational", as it actively works to achieve political goals.

---

I think we can all agree that the United Klans of America is bad. Other viewpoints of the SPLC might be more controversial, such as its take on LGBT rights. My recommendation is to look *at the actual matter at hand*. Either rejecting or accepting anything the SPLC says without at least briefly looking in to would be foolish.

Comment: Also, trust but verify (Russian Proverb). With any organization you can take them for their word, but verify their results before using any examples.

Answer (score 4):

Having a specific social, moral or ethical agenda is not the same as being political. Saying I'm against racism or hate groups might align more with a particular political party at one time or another, and might even lead one to oppose a political party because of their stances, on those issues, but that's not the same as being political.

Being political, in the context I'm getting from your question, would be taking the moral stance or position because that's what a particular group takes as their stance, or only applying that standard to one party or group.

If someone seems to apply their stances in a uniform manner (ACLU filing a lawsuit to protect Rush Limbaugh's private prescription history from review, for instance), without regard to the politics of the people involved, then we can say they are issue advocates, even if their issues seem to more closely align with one end of the political spectrum.

If someone only advocates for a particular issue, depending on who it applies to (see liberals and conservatives on the importance of: deficits, transparency, using private email servers, "rule of law", appropriate use of filibuster, use of "reconciliation", "family values," time spent golfing, etc), then it's political, masquerading as issue, moral or ethical advocacy.

Answer (score 3):

The Southern Poverty Law Center is a rather openly partisan organization that provides information on what it considers hate crimes.  Its definition of hate crimes is rather broad and includes people who have spoken to organizations that believe that homosexual acts are morally wrong.

They also condemn things like black separatism, but their definition there is much more limited.  For example, Black Lives Matter is not considered a hate group, even though some of their supporters advocate violence, particularly against [police officers](http://www.msnbc.com/the-reid-report/the-truth-about-the-dead-cops-chant).  Of course, after the deaths of two police officers, they said

> On behalf of the Millions March NYC, we express our deepest condolences to the families of the officers who were killed on Saturday. Our march last weekend was a peaceful outcry that senseless violence in our society is harmful to trust, community, and security. This tragedy is in no way connected to our march, or ongoing protests against police brutality, discrimination, and profiling – and we condemn, and are disappointed with any entity that would try to imply such connection. As New Yorkers, we will continue to march for a peaceful society, where trust between communities and law enforcement is finally achieved.

There are two problems.

1. This did not happen until after the violence.
2. They condemn people for linking the two events rather than condemning the call to violence or the actual violence.

Of course, people can point to conservative groups that do the same thing.  That pattern was common after violence at abortion clinics, although the groups have matured their message over time.

In terms of their goals, you can read their website.

For example, [Fighting Hate](https://www.splcenter.org/fighting-hate):

> We publish investigative reports, train law enforcement officers and share key intelligence, and offer expert analysis to the media and public.

That seems pretty clear on an intent to influence policy.

Or [Seeking Justice](https://www.splcenter.org/seeking-justice):

> We’ve toppled remnants of Jim Crow segregation and destroyed violent white supremacist groups. We’ve shattered barriers to equality for women, vulnerable children, the LGBT community and the disabled. We’ve protected migrant workers and immigrants from abuse, ensured the humane treatment of prisoners, reformed juvenile justice practices, and more.

In that, they claim to have already affected policy.

Comment: this answer seems to imply anti-gay groups shouldn't be considered a hate group. why?

Comment: it also seems to imply BLM, *as a group* advocates violence. this answer is just a rant.

Comment: `Black Lives Matter is not considered a hate group, even though some of their supporters advocate violence`: this is flawed logic. There are vegetarians who advocate violence. Are all vegetarians now part of a hate group? Of course not (I can go on with many more examples). There are many ways to define "hate group" (these sort of classifications are genuinely tricky), but "some members advocate violence" is most certainly not a good way to define "hate group".

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, does that mean that a group needs to be homogenous in its violence to be considered a hate group? Is there a critical mass? Does hating another group need to include violence, as in can I hate without being violent? my question came from some people on the SPLC black list claiming they are on the list because of association with another group yet they themselves do not hate. I association enough?

Comment: @FrankCedeno these are all questions you need to ask the SPLC directly. We could only speculate as to the specific criteria they use.

Comment: @FrankCedeno Like I said, it's a genuinely tricky question, but you need to try harder than "some members advocate violence". Go to /r/The_Donald and you will many people "advocate violence". There are idiots everywhere on the entire spectrum.

Comment: There is a big difference between a group's stated public goals, beliefs, and missions and those of their members. Has BLM as an organization called for violence? FRC has published anti-LBGT material on their web site.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker  You're missing my point.  It's not that they should list BLM as a hate group.  It's that they *do* list others as hate groups based on similar logic.  If someone talking at an FRC event is enough to be listed as a hate sponsor, then they should use the same logic in condemning groups associated with violence.  They should either be restrictive everywhere or use guilt by association everywhere.  I.e. they should be consistent.

Comment: @Brythan what is "FRC"? As Jaylynn states, that group has published anti-LGBT material. There is no logical inconsistency here.

Comment: To put it another way, BLM advocates for equal protection. FRC does the opposite.

Comment: @Brythan Sorry, but the SPLC did not list the FRC "based on similar logic". If you [read the website](https://www.splcenter.org/fighting-hate/extremist-files/group/family-research-council) then you see it is listed based on statements *made in official capacity* by high-ranking officials which very strongly demonize homosexuals. Some examples include "pedophilia [..] is a homosexual problem", "Gaining access to children has been a long-term goal of the homosexual movement", etc. Whether they *should* be listed on SPLC is up for grabs, but it's a far cry from BLM.

Comment: Either way, I don't think that what SPLC writes (or doesn't writes ) about BLM or FRC is really all that relevant here *for the purpose of answering this specific question*.

Comment: I didn't say they listed FRC by similar logic.  I said that they list others for attending FRC events but do not list BLM for attending events where violence is advocated.  And the basic question here is if the SPLC is biased.  Talking about how they treat different groups differently speaks to that bias.

Comment: There's a difference between openly denouncing violence, as BLM always has, and trying to incite it. To claim that BLM only made statements of anti-violence after officers were killed is simply not true.  No group can control all members or supporters.  What is the message from the organization, itself?  Is it muddled, contradictory.  Does it match with actions?  Or is it a bit "wink-wink." BLM has never advocated violence against police, and have always, formally and officially, been against it.

Comment: @Brythan unless I missed it, who are you specifically referring to when you say "people are listed by association for attending FRC events"?